Verticies of Polytope and Tropical Polynomial
Let $P$ be a polytope in $\mathbb{R}^n$ determined by the intersection $k$ half-spaces $\{H_i\}_{i=1}^k$, where
$$
H_i := \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\, \langle A_i,x\rangle \le c_i\}
$$
for some $A_1,c_1,\dots,A_k,c_k\in \mathbb{R}^n$.
So I don't do tropical geometry (at all) but it seems research question I was lead to is naturally expressible as a tropical problem (which I know nothing about); namely:

For each vertex $v\in P$: does there exist a tropical polynomial $p_v$ with coefficients written in terms of $A_1,c_1,\dots,A_k,c_k$ such that: $p_v(x)=0$ if and only if $x=v$?
If so, are there bounds on the maximal degree of $p_v$ in terms of $k$ and $n$?

A terminology issue :  $<A_i,x>\le c_i$ defines a "half-space" whereas a hyperplane is given by an equal sign : $<A_i,x>=c_i$
